# Nullpointerexception on itemclick event of listview

Tags: android

```
protected void onResume(){
        listTimer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTimer);
        fetchData();
        tadapt = new TimerAdapter(RoutineList, this);
        listTimer.setAdapter(tadapt);
        listTimer.performItemClick(v1, 0, listval);
        super.onResume();
    }

listTimer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                v1 = arg0;
                pos = arg2;
                listval = arg3;
                View v = arg0.getChildAt(arg2);
                TextView tvM = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvETimer);
}
```

Note: I got Nullpointerexception on View.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already the view is in the variable arg1.. no need to assign again to another variable v..

Try this...

```
listTimer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            v1 = arg0;
            pos = arg2;
            listval = arg3;
            TextView tvM = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tvETimer);
}
```

Comment: is your activity a list activity?? on which line the error is shown??

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have called [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) before `onResume` method and that layout contains `listTimer`. This can be the reason why your view is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all always place `super.onResume()` as the first statement of your `Activity.onResume()` method.

When you are using `findViewById()` for `ListView` set `OnItemClickListener` also.
I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this string:

```
View v = arg0.getChildAt(arg2);
```

with

```
View v = arg1;
```

Comment: Possibly view is null because there is some problems in your adapter. Check how it creates views.

Can you post TimerAdapter code?